# bottom widget outside of PageView.builder is hidden when keyboard pops up

Tags: flutter

As title says, I have a bottom bar widget that controls the PageView.builder, in the last page I have a textfield and when I tap on that and the keyboard opens, my bottom bar gets hidden, I did try for hours for solutions like:

1. Using a singleScrollChildView - it didn't work, inside of the pageview.builder I have an expanded widget so I can't use the "singleScrollChildView" widget
2. Use scaffold bottomSheet - it didn't work,somehow even with resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, the bottom widget gets hidden
3. use Stack, still didn't work

my code is like that:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final locale = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: PageView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            itemCount: 2,
            onPageChanged: (int index) {
            },
            itemBuilder: (_, currentPage) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Widget1(),
                  Widget2(),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Widget3(),
                          Widget4(
                          )
                        ],
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        BottomBarWidget(
        ),
      ]),
    );
```

}
}

Any clue of what I'm doing wrong?